# Spring App gives rg.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException When run on Linux?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

My application runs just fine on Mac OS X within Spring Tool Suite with Tomcat 7 and JDK 7u6 for Mac OS X. Same app gives me errors when I run it on RHEL 6 with Jdk7u6

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint' defined in class path resource [spring-security.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?
```

here is the relevant bean reference / definiton

```
<beans:bean id="apiAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.example.ApiAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint">
   <beans:constructor-arg name="loginUrl" value="/login" type="java.lang.String"  index="0"  />
</beans:bean>
```

Here is a snippet of the code

```
public class ApiAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint
{
    public ApiAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint(String loginUrl)
    {
        super(loginUrl);
    }
```

What could be causing such a problem?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Varun I worked around it with explicit xml configuration, never really figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you have multiple constructors accepting only one argument of type String.
Possibly not in the same class, but maybe in one that it extends.

And then spring has no clue which to call :)

However it's weird you get this error only on linux.

Comment: nope I have one constructor, this code runs just fine when complied by the eclipse compiler, fails when compiled with the Java 7 compiler.